# Given an array of integers, return all pairs that add up to 100

Tags: javascript, array, interview-questions

I was recently given this programming challenge on an interview, and I decided to use javascript to solve it. I did, but I'm not happy with my implementation. I can't help thinking there must be a better way of doing this.

The exercise goes like this:

> Given an array of integers, write a function that returns an array of
>   each pair of integers that add up to 100. The input is
>
> > [0, 1, 100, 99, 0, 10, 90, 30, 55, 33, 55, 75, 50, 51, 49, 50, 51, 49, 51]
>
> and the function should return something like this (the order is not
>   important).
>
> > [ [0,100], [1,99], [10,90], [50,50], [49,51] ]

My implementation looks like this, is there a different approach out there?

```
var sample_data = [0, 1, 100, 99, 0, 10, 90, 30, 55, 33, 55, 75, 50, 51, 49, 50, 51, 49, 51]

function process(data){

    var result = []
    var a;
    var b;

    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

        a = data[i];

        for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {

            b = data[j]

            if ( (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)) === 100 && result.indexOf(a+","+b) == -1 && result.indexOf(b+","+a ) == -1 ) {
               result.push( a+","+b )
            }

        }    
    }

    for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = result[i].split(',')
    }

    return result
} 

process(sample_data);
```

Comment: Is it possible that a pair like [-3, 103] exists, or are there no negative numbers?

Comment: are negative integers allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Style

It is considered good practice to terminate all statements with a semicolon, even though they are optional.

Follow `namingConventions` in JavaScript.

The function should have a more descriptive name than `process()`.  It could take the desired sum as a parameter.

### Algorithm

Your function, which relies on brute force, is an inefficient \$O(n^2)\$, bordering on \$O(n^3)\$.  It's \$O(n^2)\$ because `i` takes on \$n\$ values, and for each `i`, `j` takes on \$n\$ values.  The `result.indexOf(…)` operations could also be \$O(n)\$ in the worst case, so the overall complexity could be as bad as \$O(n^3)\$.

One simple optimization would be to take advantage of symmetry to cut the work in half:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    a = data[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        …
    }
}
```

Another simplification would be to avoid stringifying and parsing the number pairs:

```
result.push([a, b]);
```

One possible smart solution would be to sort the data, and have `i` increasing from 0, and `j` decreasing from the end, until they meet in the middle.

```
function pairsWithSum(sum, data) {
    data = data.slice(0);
    data.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });

    var pairs = [];
    var i = 0, j = data.length - 1;
    while (i < j && i < data.length && j >= 0) {
        var a = data[i], b = data[j];

        if (a + b == sum) {
            pairs.push([a, b]);
            while (i < data.length && data[i] == a) { i++; }
            while (j >= 0 && data[j] == b) { j--; }
        } else if (a + b < sum) {
            while (i < data.length && data[i++] == a);
        } else {
            while (j >= 0 && data[j--] == b);
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Comment: Why is the "smart" solution to use an `O(n lg n)` algorithm when an `O(n)` algorithm exists? =]

Comment: Not `O(n s)`, more like `O(n + s)`.

Comment: *Five* while loops? No offense, but that's a terrible solution. Jodrell [has a much better one.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74187/5903) "There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies, and the other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies." -- Tony Hoare

Answer (score 13):

okay, my javascript is not great but this should find all pairs in a single pass.

**this assumes all values are between 0 and 100**, like in the question.

Here is a [working JSFiddle that shows the code in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/dgajvn2k/5/)

```
var sample_data = [0, 1, 100, 99, 0, 10, 90, 30, 55, 33, 55, 75, 50, 51,
                      49, 50, 51, 49, 51];

var found = {};
var results = [];
for(var i of sample_data) {
    if (found[100 - i] === true) {
        // pair found
        results.push({
            a: i,
            b: 100 - i
        });
    }

    found[i] = true;
}
```

essentially, `found` is used as a hashset to see if the required reciprocal has already occurred in the array.

This makes the code more concise while being as easy to understand, therefore  more maintainable. The code is also likely to have superior performance to code with nested loops.

Comment: Jodrell, yours is obviously the optimum solution.  I made a few changes: 1. set the `found` first, so [50,50] will work, 2. returned an array rather than an object, as spec'ed, 3. removed an unnecessary comparison.

Comment: I like this. However, you need to use `sample_data[i]` almost everywhere where you wrote `i`.

Comment: @200_success, I know this is old but, I added a working JS Fiddle to show this code working, I think you misunderstand.

Comment: OK. I missed the fact that you used `var i of sample_data` instead of `var i in sample_data` — a relatively new JavaScript feature.

Comment: [Non-Review answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4978/12462): You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed  the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @200_success after looking at the version history I think that you missed nothing on Dec 19 2014. This code that contains a correct loop construct was posted about one and a half year later.

Comment: @200_success, actually my earlier  version was just wrong in a more fundamental way, there is no `foreach` in javascript. I improved this, about a year after your comment. Anyway, I think its better now.

Comment: @miracle173, I've extended the answer to show what I was thinking. Please edit if you want to add. This is clearly a superior way of approaching the problem. If you feel it doesn't meet the rules, delete it.

Answer (score 5):

### Nitpicks

```
function process(data){
```

On an interview question, I'd prefer to see an answer like

```
function find_pairs_that_sum_to(numbers, sum) {
```

That way I can see that you write readable, reusable code.

```
var result = []
var a;
```

I find code like this confusing.  Why no `;` on the first line?  Why on the second line?  I'd prefer to see consistency in the formatting.  Also, I'd name `result` `pairs`.

```
        if ( (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)) === 100 && result.indexOf(a+","+b) == -1 && result.indexOf(b+","+a ) == -1 ) {
           result.push( a+","+b )
        }
```

Considering that [`indexOf` is \$O(n)\$](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19287033/2625983), you might want to avoid doing it twice.

```
        b = parseInt(data[j]);
        if ( (a + b) === sum ) {
          if ( a <= b ) {
            if ( -1 == pairs.indexOf(a+","+b) ) {
              pairs.push( a+","+b );
            }
          } else {
            if ( -1 == pairs.indexOf(b+","+a) ) {
              pairs.push( b+","+a );
            }
          }

          // we don't need to try any more once we have a match
          // move to the next outer loop value
          break;
        }
```

Note that your algorithm is \$O(n^3)\$.  One \$n\$ for each loop and a third for the `indexOf`.  You can argue \$O(n^2m)\$ where \$m\$ is the size of the solution, but the bad case is where the solution is half as large as the input.

### Alternative

One of the other answers mentioned using a map, and that will work.  However, for working with numbers, an array may do fine.  Of course, this stops working if the problem space becomes big.  It works fine for a hundred values though.

```
function find_pairs_that_sum_to(numbers, sum) {
  var is_in_numbers = [];

  for ( var i = 0; i < sum; ++i ) {
    is_in_numbers.push(false);
  }

  for ( var i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i ) {
    // assumes that all values in numbers are in [0, sum]
    // if that can be untrue, bad values should be caught here

    is_in_numbers[parseInt(numbers[i])] = true;
  }

  var pairs = [];
  var n = sum / 2;
  for ( var i = 0; i <= n; ++i ) {
    if ( is_in_numbers[i] && is_in_numbers[sum - i] ) {
      pairs.push([i, sum - i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Testing on your sample data produces almost the same result, only the order differs.  This function is linear against the solution space (i.e. 101 in this case) or the number of inputs, whichever is larger.  You could write that as \$O(m + n)\$

If the solution space is much larger than the number of inputs, then you can change `is_in_numbers` from an array to a map.  That would give you a straight \$O(n)\$ solution.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, given this is an interview question, an important aspect is to be asking questions. It's very common in the real world to be given a vague spec or a problem that has not been fully considered. If you don't ask, ensure that your program can handle such edge-cases. Be defensive with your code and try to have a bulletproof spec.

Secondly, tests. A great way to blow an interviewer over is to write your tests first, or at least suggest that you would before you start coding. Thinking about tests can help cover the questions that you should be asking anyway and edge-cases you may not have originally thought of, although for the sake of brevity during an interview, they may end up just being a talking point.

As for the problem in question, for the given data set, a naive approach is not going to struggle on a modern computer and if it is genuinely faster for you to code, you could argue that is the fastest solution on that basis. There are some traps to avoid, depending on your approach; a big one depends on interpretation of the problem statement 'return... each pair of integers that add up to 100'. It's not clear if that means that if 0 occurs three times and 100 occurs five times, we should see three pairs of [0, 100] or just a single unique pair. Including all pairs is a more interesting challenge, so I'll assume that from now on until I say otherwise.

The fastest and most scalable algorithm is to build a histogram, that is, to count the number of occurrences of the values (a map or an array can be suitable here). In javascript, using an array, that might look something like this:

```
var histogram = [101];

for(var i=0; i<histogram.length; i++) { // init
    histogram[i] = 0;
}

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { // populate
    histogram[data[i]]++;
}
```

Once you have a histogram, we can observe that number pairs that add up to 100 mirror either side of 50 and, as a result, 50 is a special case. For non-50 numbers, we have as many pairs as the smaller frequency of occurrence. Put into code:

```
var result = [];

for(var i=0; i<floor(histogram[50]/2); i++) {
    result.push([50, 50]);
}

for(var number=0; number<50; number++) {
    var inverse = 100 - number;
    var pair = [number, inverse];
    var numberFrequency = histogram[number];
    var inverseFrequency = histogram[inverse];
    var pairCount = numberFrequency < inverseFrequency ? numberFrequency : inverseFrequency;

    for(var i=0; i<pairCount; i++) {
        result.push(pair);
    }
}
```

Obviously this approach needs some adjustment if negative numbers are allowed and would probably want to use a map instead to avoid having a potentially sparse and large array. Overall, it only takes O(n) to insert into the histogram and the other aspects are constant, making this approach optimal.

If we do want to do unique pairs, as per your implementation and the alternative interpretation of the problem statement, we can just change the print loops to if statements. However, there is also an extra end condition: if you have encountered all possible pairs, we no longer need to continue building the histogram and can just print all possible pairs and finish. We can adjust the histogram population code to catch this:

```
// snip: histogram creation and initialisation

var encountered = -1;

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { // populate
    histogram[data[i]]++;

    if(data[i] == encountered + 1) {
        while(histogram[encountered + 1] > 0) {
            encountered++;
        }
        if(encountered == 100) {
            for(var i=0; i<51; i++) {
                result.push([i, 100 - i]);
            }
            break; //end early
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to code in JavaScript, but here are a few algorithms you can use:

- Take a integer and run through the loop to find 100-arr[i]. (The one you used)
  Time complexity: \$O(n^2)\$
- Sort the array (\$O(nlogn)\$) and traverse the array from both the ends to get the pairs

  Say a sorted array is: {1,3,50,50,97}.

  - Traverse the array with `startIndex = 0` and `endIndex` = array's size-1
  - Run the loop to see if `arr[startIndex]+arr[endIndex]=N` (100)
  - If = record and increment `startIndex` and decrement `endIndex`
  - If < increment `startIndex`
  - else (If >) decrement `endIndex`.
- Have a map with key as the `arr[i]` and key as its count. Time complexity \$O(n)\$ and space complexity \$O(n)\$.

  - Check if `N-arr[i]` is present in the Map.
  - If not, put the arr[i] into the map and increment its value.
  - If yes, you have a pair. Enjoy. Remember to decrement `N-arr[i]`

Answer (score 2):

I present an algorithms in pseudocode. Actually  I don't use some pseudocode grammar invented by me but I use Python and avoid Python specific idioms. I think this is readable even if one has no knowledge of Python at all but nevertheless it has a precise meaning and can be executed and tested (e.g. [here](https://repl.it/@miracle173/StaleAnchoredAgama)).

---

The following algorithm   will do it in \$O(n \log(n)\$ time and $O(n)$ space. \$O(n \log(n)\$ time is needed for sorting the array. Scanning the sorted array and finding the solutions takes \$O(n)\$ time, because each list element is accessed at most once. Your algorithm will take \$O(n^2)\$ time, because you execute two nested `for` loop, each of them stepping through the number list of length \$n\$.

```
number=[0, 1, 100, 99, 0, 10, 90, 30, 55, 33, 55, 75, 50, 51, 49, 50, 51, 49, 51]
target=100
number.sort()
i=0
j=len(number)-1
lo=number[i]
hi=number[j]
while (True):
    sum=lo+hi
    if sum > target:
        j=j-1
        if j<=i:
            break
        hi=number[j]
    elif sum<target:
        i=i+1
        if i>=j:
            break
        lo=number[i]
    else:
        print(lo,hi)
        j=j-1
        i=i+1
        if ((i>=j)):
            break
        lo=number[i]
        hi=number[j]
```

Comment: Please give a little bit more information. Why is the algorithm better? What makes it more efficient?

Comment: @TopinFrassi: I introduced two variables `s1`, `s2` that facilitate the description. I hope it is clearer now (if you are familiar with the Big O notation)

Comment: I could write some code in C# or say, SmallTalk that would be concise, readable and have superior performance but since the question is about JavaScript what would be the point?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of your `sum` quantity, in this case 100, you may want to consider making multiple passes. I've thrown together a quick piece of code that passes my basic tests, although clearly you'd want to perform your own tests!

```
var pairsWithSum = function(sum, data) {

    // make an array to see how many counts we have
    var counts = new Array(sum + 1);

    // count the number of times each element comes up
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(!counts[data[i]]) {
            counts[data[i]] = 1
        }
        else {
            counts[data[i]]++;
        }
    }

    var pairs = [];
    // walk up from the start of the counts, and
    // match that number with the its "sum - i" pair
    // since that's the only number that will reach the sum
    for(var i = 0; i <= sum / 2; i++) {
        var first = i;
        var last = sum - i;

        // we may have duplicates, for example `pairsWithSum(10, [2,2,8,8]);
        // will have two entries in this code
        while(counts[first] > 0 && counts[last] > 0) {
            pairs.push([first, last]);
            counts[first]--;
            counts[last]--;
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

This is not without its downfalls, though. Consider something like `pairsWithSum(100000000,[1,2,3])` - do we really want to allocate an array of 1000000000 to find pairs in 3 numbers? No, not really. In that case, we'd probably want the logarithmic solution.

I personally would have both implementations, and use a threshold to determine which one is which, programatically determining the threshold based on your target environment and resource constraints. A quick rule of thumb I would use is if `n * lg(n) < sum` then you would want to use the logarithmic version. Otherwise, use the memory-hog we have here. But which you use in production depends heavily on your resource constraints.

Comment: "do we really want to allocate an array... we'd probably want the logarithmic solution"  Look into how arrays are actually handled in JavaScript.  I'm not sure there is a difference here.

Comment: I'm sure there is a difference. It's constant time to index into an array. It's linear time to iterate over an array. Even in JavaScript. It does do funky things if you pass strings (which we're not doing) but even then it's still constant time to access.

Comment: Well, if you're sure.

Comment: Or, instead of being passive aggressive, you could instead find the evidence that says it's not constant time to access an array or linear time to iterate over the array. Because I have looked into it and was unable to find any evidence to the contrary. But I am open to the fact I might not have a complete understanding of it, so please - show me something that invalidates my assumption so I may have the most correct answer possible.

Comment: Sorry, I was irritated by "Why is the "smart" solution to use an O(n lg n) algorithm when an O(n) algorithm exists?"  http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/understanding-javascript-arrays/

Comment: Just read the entire article. Nowhere does it say anything that invalidates my assumptions about the complexity of using an array.

Comment: Third Sentence: "A JavaScript array is simply a glorified object with a unique constructor and literal syntax and an additional set of properties and methods inherited from Array.prototype"  We can conclude it is not an actual data structure the way it is with other languages, but an object with these properties: "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", ...

Sorry again for the snide remarks.

Comment: But can you conclude that it's not constant time to access a single element? I don't believe there's any evidence of that.