# Finding the first two numbers that sum to a given number

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

> **Task aim:** Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of
>   appearance that add up to form the sum.

I've been trying to make my implemented function below run faster (less than 7000ms) and taking into account records upwards of 10,000,000 items.

While it works for basic tests such as these:

```
sum_pairs( [1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8 ) == [1, 7]
sum_pairs( [1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6 ) == [0, -6]
sum_pairs( [20, -13, 40], 7 ) == undefined
sum_pairs( [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 2 ) == [1, 1] 
sum_pairs( [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10 ) == [3, 7] 
sum_pairs( [4, -2, 3, 3, 4], 8 ) == [4, 4]
sum_pairs( [0, 2, 0], 0 ) == [0, 0]
sum_pairs( [5, 9, 13, -3], 10 ) == [13, -3]
```

it breaks with some other unseen tests (which presumably have some tricky 'edge cases' and thus, breaks my implementation which I suspect isn't an optimal solution.

It's been weeks now and I really would appreciate some guidance or signpost to some helpful resource to set me on the right track.

```
var sum_pairs = function (ints, s) {
    //your code here
    var i = 0,
    j = 0,
    len = ints.length,
    min = undefined,
    count = 0;

    for (i; i < len; i++) {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < len) {
           if (s - ints[i] === ints[j]) {
               if ( !min || (j < min[1]) ) {
                   min = [i, j];

                   // Check if worth continuing
                   close = (i+1===j);
                   if ( close ) break;
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (min !== undefined){
        min[0] = parseInt(ints[min[0]]);
        min[1] = parseInt(ints[min[1]]);
    }
    return min
}
```

Comment: "it breaks with some other unseen tests" - Is that what it says, or is it what you believe is the case? If this is a code challenge somewhere, exceeding the completion time is usually also a failure condition.

Comment: @Sumurai8 It is indeed a coding challenge and the error shown is about my code exceeding the completion time. Hence why it isn't being accepted.

Comment: Isn't it an exact duplicate of [Codewars: Sum of Pairs](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/138216) ?

Comment: @wOxxOm Similar, but not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @wOxxOm That is indeed the challenge I am tackling. Could you offer some guidance on how best I may optimise my effort so far?

Comment: @wOxxOm Apologies but I've just now followed your link and seen it's a solution from you, not just a reference to the origin of the question. Funny thing is tho: the linked question was from me! I hadn't for some reason received notification of it being answered and it doesn't show up under my profile of 'Questions'. Strange. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues with the code:

- `close` isn't defined anywhere and will shoot up to the global scope.
- Your variables are terribly named. Use names that make sense.
- Suggesting a `var` per variable so they become portable. You can easily copy and paste without having to remove the comma and re-add the `var`.
- I am not sure why you would need `parseInt` for the end part of your logic when `ints` appears to be an array of numbers.
- Prefer function declaration (`function foo(){}`) over function expression (`var foo = function(){}`). Although variables and functions have the same namespace, function declarations get hoisted. They will always be available regardless if they appear later in the code.
- JS uses camelCase convention.

For performance:

- I suggest you keep a hash of first values so that whenever they come up again, like `[ 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 7]`, you can skip the second time it occurs, saving you a full run through the array.

Here's my take on it:

```
function sumPairs(numbers, sum){
  let first = null;
  let second = null;
  let firstHistory = {};

  for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    first = numbers[i]

    // Skip if we've already seen this number as the first number
    if(firstHistory[first]) continue;

    // Remember that we've seen this number before
    firstHistory[first] = true;

    for(let j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
      second = numbers[j];

      // Skip if we're on the same index
      if(i === j) continue;

      // Return once we've found it. Forget the rest.
      if(first + second === sum) return [first, second];
    }
  }

  // The only time the function ever reaches this point is when it never
  // returned (it never found the values). Functions return an implicit
  // undefined, which satisfies your "not found" case.
}
```

It doesn't cover one test case though. It sees `[10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5]` as `[5, 5]` instead of `[3, 7]`. However, the definition of "earlier" in the condition is not clear. `[5, 5]` is found earlier than `[3, 7]` from an execution perspective.

And it might not be perfect, but the idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

### Limited by the second number

When I first read this challenge, I did not understand why you did not break out of the loop as soon as you found a candidate. After looking at your code again, you want to have the following test case return `[6,2]` and not `[1,7]`.

```
sum_pairs([1,6,2,7], 8) === [6,2];
```

You want the second number to be as early as possible in the array. So write your algorithm that way.

```
var sum_pairs = function (ints, s) {
    let len = ints.length;
    let min = undefined;

    outerloop:
    for (let j = 1; j < len; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
           if (s - ints[i] === ints[j]) {
               min = [ints[i], ints[j]];
               break outerloop;
           }
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

Now, if you have something like this you are done in one step.

```
sum_pairs([1,2, ...], 3);
```

But, Sumurai8, what about those odd lists with 1 or 0 elements? Well, glad you asked. The for-loop does not run if the end-condition is not met. The outer loop will never be run if `len <= 1`.

### Wrong test case

The following test case should not return `undefined`, but instead should return `[20,-13]`, as their sum is indeed `7`.

```
sum_pairs( [20, -13, 40], 7 )
```

### Close?

The following snippet is odd:

```
   // Check if worth continuing
   close = (i+1===j);
   if ( close ) break;
```

That's a very very unlikely edge-case. You probably meant to do `min[1]`, which is an optimization that works in slightly more cases.

### Style

Look at your whitespace. In particular around operators.

Don't declare variables with the comma notation. You will end up dropping your variables into the global scope, which is not what you want. Instead write each variable on a new line, with preferably `let` or `const` before it (or `var` if you are developing for old browsers).

You have unused variables (in this case only `count`).

Don't simulate for-loops with while-loops. You can omit arguments of `for` if you do not need them. E.g.

```
for( ; i < kittens.length; i++ ) { }
```

Comment: Thanks Sumurai8 for your answer. It's offered me some insight and you were indeed right about the **undefined** answer being wrong: but that's a typo I made. The passed in variable is **-7** and not 7.